# Using Filter in spark dataframes (python)

Tags: apache-spark

I am having a dataframe with the following format:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | values |
+------+--------+
| 1    |[1,2,3] |
+------+--------+
| 2    |[1,2,3] |
+------+--------+
| 3    |[1,3]   |
+------+--------+
| 4    |[1,2,8] |
      .
      .
      .
```

And I want to filter and take the rows that the length of the list of the values column is equal or more than 3. Assuming that the dataframe is called `df` i am doing the following:

```
udf_filter = udf(lambda value: len(alist)>=3,BooleanType())
filtered_data = df.filter(udf_filter("values"))
```

When I run:

```
filtered_data.count()
```

It always give different result. How can it be possible?

Notes:

1. `df` comes from another dataframe by sampling it (same seed)
2. `df.count` always give the same number

**Edit:**
I am using the following code to take the sample from the original table:

```
df = df_original.sample(False, 0.01, 42)
```

Even though that I am using `seed=42` if I run it multiple times it will not give the same results. To avoid that I persist the df and it gives always the same results:

```
df.persist()
```

But what I dont understand is that `seed` doesnt give the same sample rows. What could be a reason for that?

Comment: a) This doesn't require UDF, b) If `df` results from sampling and you don't use fixed seed then it is extremely unlikely to get the same count on each run, hence `filtered_data.count`  will differ on each execution

Comment: @zero323 seed is the same every time. Which is the way to do it without UDF?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size